# SQL Concatenation Query - Four As in Concatenated Name

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a view in SQL.  We will call this view "A7T8".  The view will pull first and last names from the database, and concatenate the first and last names into a field called FullName.  However, I only want to select the concatenated names that have a total of at least four As in their first and last names.  (Rebecca Aaronson would not be displayed since she only has 3 As, but Harry Flanagan would be displayed.

Currently my code is:

```
CREATE VIEW A7T8 AS
SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME AS FULLNAME
FROM A7
WHERE Upper(LNAME) LIKE '%A%A%A%A%' OR Upper(FNAME) LIKE '%A%A%A%A%'
ORDER BY LNAME, FNAME;
```

But this only pulls names that have four As in the first name or four As in the last name.  I want it to pull names that have a total of at least four As in the concatenated full name.  How do I do this?

Comment: what is the dbms being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
CREATE VIEW A7T8 AS
SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME AS FULLNAME
FROM A7
WHERE UPPER(FNAME || ' ' || LNAME) LIKE '%A%A%A%A%'
ORDER BY LNAME, FNAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach

```
CREATE VIEW A7T8 AS
select FNAME + ' ' + LNAME AS FULLNAME
from [A7]
where len(FNAME  + LNAME) - len(Replace(Upper(FNAME) + Upper(LNAME),'A','')) >= 4
ORDER BY LNAME, FNAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Concat do the job, you must use it in a query not with the designer

```
CREATE VIEW  [dbo].[DEMO_VIEW]
AS

 SELECT Concat('IND_', LIBELLE)  as SECONDLIBELLE,
        CODE as SECONDCODE

        from dbo.DEMOTABLE

GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a REGEX. This will match first last with 1-4 A's

CREATE VIEW A7T8 AS
SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME AS FULLNAME
FROM A7
WHERE CONCAT(Upper(LNAME), " ", Upper(FNAME)) REGEX '[A]{1,4}'
ORDER BY LNAME, FNAME;